# How i can exact output

Tags: c++

I write a code to sort a set of strings by their size.If the size of the strings are equal, must maintain the original order of the set.

when i input-->Top Coder comp Wedn at midnight

my code give me output is-->midnight Coder Wedn come at midnight

But i want output-->midnight Coder comp Wedn Top at

```
while(cin>>k){
        if(k=="m")
        break;
      w.push_back(k);
}
cout<<w.size()<<"\n";


for(i=0;i<w.size();i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<w.size();j++)
    {
        if(w[i].size()>1&&w[i].size()<50&&w[j].size()>1&&w[j].size()<50)
        {
        if(w[i].size()<w[j].size()&&i!=j)
            {
                string temp;
                temp=w[i];
                w[i]=w[j];
                w[j]=temp;
            }
            else if(w[i].size()==w[j].size()&&i!=j)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<w.size();i++)
{
    cout<< w[i]<<" ";
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what is expected and what is not. In particular, we don't do code reviews. Either pinpoint your problem to a specific issue or try moving this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why the many conditions on `size()`, and why are you testing whether `i != j`?

Comment: w.size() total lenght of string element in vector.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler way to do that in C++ using [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Input strings from cin into a vector
    vector<string> v(istream_iterator<string>(cin), {});

    // sort vector based on lengths and preserve ordering
    stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const string & a, const string & b) -> bool {
        return a.length() > b.length();
    });

    // print contents of vector to cout
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
Top Coder comp Wedn at midnight
```

Output

```
midnight Coder comp Wedn Top at
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://www.ideone.com/M74jUW)

Comment: Use `std::stable_sort` instead.